# PostgreSQL Case expression in Group By block has no effect

Tags: sql, postgresql

I don't usually write sql and have run into this problem. While using case statements. This is a simplified version of the function that still gets the same error:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION retrieve_test(
  _period interval
)
returns table(
  profit double precision,
  bid double precision,
  ask double precision
) as $$
begin
    raise notice 'Value: %', _period;
    return query
        SELECT
            (CASE WHEN _period IS NOT NULL THEN AVG(o.profit) ELSE o.profit END)::double precision,
            o.bid, o.ask
    FROM opportunities o
    GROUP by 
    case WHEN _period is NULL then 1 end,
    2,3;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE PLPGSQL;
```

I get the following error:

```
SQL Error [42803]: ERROR: column "o.profit" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
  Where: PL/pgSQL function retrieve_test(interval) line 4 at RETURN QUERY
```

When I run any of the following queries:

```
select * from retrieve_test(null);
--or
select * from retrieve_test('1 minute'::interval);
```

I'm not sure if this is the correct structure for this type of query. What am I missing.

```
Running:
postgres:14.2 docker image
```

Answer (score 1):

The error tells you everything. You **must** have columns, that you listed in a `select`, to be present in a `group by` clause, if the columns are not aggregated.

[The PostgreSQL documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html)

From the link above:

> When GROUP BY is present, or any aggregate functions are present, it is not valid for the SELECT list expressions to refer to ungrouped columns except within aggregate functions or when the ungrouped column is functionally dependent on the grouped columns, since there would otherwise be more than one possible value to return for an ungrouped column. A functional dependency exists if the grouped columns (or a subset thereof) are the primary key of the table containing the ungrouped column.

Comment: What I'm trying to do isn't possible then

Comment: I would rather call the table bids, as it seems more appropriate. Use `window function` avg with a combination of something like `coalsedce` of your DBMS.